# How to enable Daily Summary report like Fabric?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I would like to receive Daily Summary report emails like Fabric for my mobile apps. It is really helpful to track how my apps are going. But after migrating from Fabric, I couldn't receive these emails anymore.

How to enable it again in Firebase?

[image: A Fabric daily summary template]

Comment: Please file a feature request with Firebase support if the product doesn't do what you would like.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I have summited a request there. 
For people who also want this feature please do a summit there. I think the more requests we make on a feature, the higher change the Google team have a look on it.